# How increase filesystem size on ubuntu running inside windows

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, wubi, filesystem, gparted

I am using ubuntu 14.04 and currently i am running it in the inside windows mode installed with Wubi. My problem is my filesystem is running on low disk space. Can i extend the filesystem size without affecting my file? How could i do that?

Comment: First backup your data and then make a clean install on a separate partition.

Answer (score 1):

Wubi? I'm pretty sure that wasn't supported for 14.04...do you mean the 'Install Ubuntu alongside Windows' option? However, Helio is right, you can't really modify a partition size once it's made.

So, you need to:

1. Backup everything (Windows and Ubuntu) using the backup tools (search 'Backup' in the Dash and Start Screen/Menu) to some large storage that you have (External USB storage is good).
2. Backup very important files separately - just copy and paste them onto some storage - it has been known for backup tools to fail.
3. Find a Windows Boot Disc and reinstall Windows. If it asks, tell it to use the whole hard drive for its partition.
   3b. If this fails, you may need to use a tool such as Gparted Live to format the internal computer storage as NTFS first.
4. When installing Ubuntu, use the custom tool for partitioning when it asks you how you want to partition. This can be tricky, use [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation) bearing how large you want your Ubuntu partition to be in mind.
5. Use the backup tools to restore your backups.
6. If they fail to recover essential files, copy them over.
7. You should now have Ubuntu and Windows partitions the size you want with all your files restored!

Comment: Yes , what I meant is the Install Ubuntu inside Windows option. I used  `wubi.exe --force`  command from windows to install ubuntu inside windows.

Comment: Wubi was [dropped over a year before 14.04](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2033316/ubuntu-13-04-raring-ringtail-drops-wubi-in-final-beta) for good reason, it was really buggy. If you want to get a bigger Ubuntu partition you really need to remove Wubi and then install Ubuntu alongside Windows with a custom partition size.

You can try the possible duplicate link in the comment on your post for help with Wubi however - but it is completely unsupported.